How to set a physical serial number for Hyper-V VM virtual disk (vhdx)?
This is not duplicate of Change the volume serial number on a VM hard drive.
In host, I can get the serial number of the physical disk.

In Hyper-V VM, I can not get it.

I know VMWare can set this with adding disk.EnableUUID=True into the VM config file. But how to do this for Hyper-V?
